# Get month and year from date cells Excel

Tags: excel

I want to isolate `month` and `year` from a date column, but this column has two formats:

***08 May 2011 00:59*** and ***08-05-2011***.

If I want to have a new column to isolate month and year from this column like: ***05-2011***, how should I do that?

Comment: Do both those cells have Date type values in different display format or they are both text values?

Comment: They both have date type values

Answer (score 11):

Try this formula (it will return value from `A1` as is if it's not a date):

```
=TEXT(A1,"mm-yyyy")
```

Or this formula (it's more strict, it will return `#VALUE` error if `A1` is not date):

```
=TEXT(MONTH(A1),"00")&"-"&YEAR(A1)
```

Comment: this format 08 May 2011 00:59 will still return the same 08 May 2011 00:59.

Comment: This would mean that `08 May 2011 00:59` is a text value, not date.

Comment: This worked for me. Have you checked the format of the cell you typed the formula into?

Comment: I have added another formula to my answer, try it too.

Comment: Check also the format of the column/cells with dates. It might be Text format or a string.

Comment: I have checked the format for both type, they are both date cells, but I can't change format to "mm-yyyy" for 08 May 2011 00:59 . Maybe I can use if statment to islate month and year for both formats?

Comment: Try writing this formula: `=A1+0`. If it gives an error, then you don't have date format in `A1`. Do you have English version of Excel and system language settings or some regional?

Comment: It gives an error, but when I do right click it and try to format it to date cell, nothing change. I use Danish version of Excel, all system settings are in Danish :(

Comment: Then I guess you have to set all those cells to date format and manually retype each date and check if they are ok by adding a zero.

Comment: It is impossible to retype each row when i have over 50,000 rows :( when i use is.text to 08 May 2011 00:59, it shows true. Can I isolate may 2011 with some build-in functions?

Answer (score 1):

[Please try](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/256359/flag-try-this-code-answers-as-very-low-quality) something like:

```
=IF(LEN(C1)>10,VALUE(LEFT(C1,FIND(" ",C1,8))),IF(ISTEXT(C1),DATE(RIGHT(C1,4),MID(C1,4,2),LEFT(C1,2)),C1))
```

You seem to have three main possible scenarios:

1. Space-separated date with time as text  (eg as A1 below)
2. Hyphen-separated date as text (eg as A2 below)
3. Formatted date index (as A4 and A5 below)

ColumnA below is formatted [General](http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/excel-help/reset-a-number-format-HP005248831.aspx) and ColumnB as Date (my default setting). ColumnC also as date but with custom formatting to suit the appearances mentioned in your question.
A clue as to whether or not text format is the left or right alignment of the cells’ contents.

I am suggesting separate treatment for each of the above three main cases, so use [=IF](http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/excel-help/if-HP005209118.aspx) to differentiate them.

### Case #1

This is longer than any of the others, so can be distinguished as having a length greater than say 10 characters, with [=LEN](http://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/len.php).
In this case we want all but the last six characters but for added flexibility (for instance, in case the time element included seconds) I have chosen to count from the left rather than from the right. The problem then is that the month names may vary in length, so I have chosen to look for the space that immediately follows the year to indicate the limit for the relevant number of characters.

This with [=FIND](http://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/find.php) which looks for a space (`" "`) in `C1`, starting with the eighth character within `C1` counting from the left, on the assumption that for this case days will be expressed as two characters and months as three *or more*.

Since =LEFT is a string function it returns a string, but this can be converted to a value with[=VALUE](http://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/value.php).

So

```
=VALUE(LEFT(C1,FIND(" ",C1,8)))
```

returns `40671` in this example – in [Excel’s 1900 date system](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/214330) the date serial number for May 5, 2011.

### Case #2

If the length of C1 is not greater than 10 characters, we still need to distinguish between a text entry or a value entry which I have chosen to do with [=ISTEXT](http://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/istext.php) and, where the if condition is TRUE (as for C2) apply [=DATE](http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/excel-help/date-function-HA102753066.aspx) which takes three parameters, here provided by:

```
=RIGHT(C2,4)
```

Takes the last four characters of C2, hence `2011` in this example.

```
=MID(C2,4,2)
```

Starting at the fourth character, takes the next two characters of C2, hence `05` in this example (representing May).

```
=LEFT(C2,2))
```

Takes the first two characters of C2, hence `08` in this example (representing the 8th day of the month).
Date is not a text function so does not need to be wrapped in =VALUE.

Taken together

```
=DATE(RIGHT(C2,4),MID(C2,4,2),LEFT(C2,2))
```

also returns `40671` in this example, but from different input from Case #1.

### Case #3

Is simple because already a date serial number, so just

```
=C2
```

is sufficient.

---

Put the above together to cover all three cases in a single formula:

```
=IF(LEN(C1)>10,VALUE(LEFT(C1,FIND(" ",C1,8))),IF(ISTEXT(C1),DATE(RIGHT(C1,4),MID(C1,4,2),LEFT(C1,2)),C1))
```

as applied in ColumnF (formatted to suit OP) or in General format (to show values are integers) in ColumnH:

[image: SO23928568 example]

Answer (score 0):

You could right click on those cells, go to format, select custom, then type mm yyyy.

Answer (score -2):

I had a requirement to provide a report showing details by month where the date field was formatted as date & time, I simply changed the formatting of the date column to "General" and then used the following formula in a new column,

```
=CONCATENATE(YEAR(C2),MONTH(C2))
```